# what is default url for deployed JAX-WS service

Tags: java, jetty, jax-ws

I need to port JEE based web service to plain spring/maven/JAX-WS/jetty. I received existing project as a template. It compiles and deploys but I face stupid problem: how to find, where the service was deployed?

Service endpoint interface:

```
@WebService(name = "myService")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL,    parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface MyEndpoint {
```

Implementation:

```
@SchemaValidation
@WebService(endpointInterface = "package.MyEndpoint",
        portName = "MyServicePort", serviceName = "myService")
public class MyEndpointImpl implements MyEndpoint {
```

Jetty startup log:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.24:run (default-cli) @ MyBackend ---
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: MyBackend Maven Webapp
[INFO] Webapp source directory = D:\Dev\prototypy\MyBackend\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO]  jetty-env.xml = D:\Dev\prototypy\MyBackend\src\main\resources\jetty\jetty-env.xml
[INFO] Classes = D:\Dev\prototypy\MyBackend\target\classes
[INFO] Logging to org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
[INFO] Context path = /my-ws
[INFO] Tmp directory =  determined at runtime
[INFO] Web defaults = org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = D:\Dev\prototypy\MyBackend\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = D:\Dev\prototypy\MyBackend\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Starting jetty 6.1.24 ...
[INFO] jetty-6.1.24
[INFO] No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
[INFO] Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

I tried all combinations, but I always receive 404 error

```
http://localhost:8080/my-ws/myService
http://localhost:8080/my-ws/myEndpoint
http://localhost:8080/my-ws/MyEndpoint
```

How to find default URI for deployed endpoint? Thanks

Comment: I thought it would be defined in the wsdl?

Comment: I use annotations. And to download WSDL I need to know service URL.

Comment: Have you tried without "my-ws" like localhost:8080/myService

Comment: I actually missed web.xml which contained CXFServlet and contextConfigLocation definitions. Then it was clear what I shall do.